# MacOS Disk Utility, can't create a partition bigger then 1,8gb even when I have 90GB available

Tags: bootcamp, disk-utility, partition

I can't create a new partition with disk utility with more then 1,8 gb of storage, I'm guessing this is the problem that is stopping boot camp from running.

[image]

I have 90GB available, why have the startup partition fully allocated everything? What can I do about this?